# how to call two different http connections in asynctask

Tags: android

How to call two different network url in asynctask background and call `onPostExecute` separately? Any idea help me please. Below is my code which works for one network connection. In my App there're two different network connections.

```
public class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            String query = URLEncoder.encode("American%20Cheese%20Burger", "utf-8");
            String url = "http://198.57.208.46.xyz";
            Log.i("url",""+url);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url); 
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return _response;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tv.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have two diffrent url how do i acce on postexecute from background???

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the Java way (Threadpools) there's the Android way with two possibilities.

- Call `doInBackground()` with two parameters (actually as much as you like). This will call `onPostExecute()` once at the end.
- Additionally override `AsyncTask.onPostProgress()` and call it on every url with `publishProgress(_response);`. This will then be called on every url and in UI-Thread, so it should fulfill your requirements. The code looks like this:

  ```
  public class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          for(String url : urls) {
              Log.i("url", url);
              // Work with the URL, like reading the JSON and build _response
              publishProgress(_response);
          }
          return _response;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(String _response) {
           super.onProgressUpdate(_response);
           tv.setText(_response);
      }
  }
  ```
- If this is still not exactly, what you need, there's a third thing you can do: Build two AsyncTasks and run them in parallel.

Comment: no accorting to my need both url have diffrent json data and i want to use that data so how do i get two diffrent url response on postexecute???

Comment: That's what I wrote. Instead of `onPostExecute` you need to work with `onPostProgress`. This you can call in your for-loop in `doInBackground` with `publishProgress`.

Comment: can you give an example of creating two `AsyncTask` that run in parallel ?